# How to use less logger.isDebugEnabled()

Tags: java, log4j

Here i will add logger.isDebugEnabled() conditional statement for logger.debug().
But sometime there are many logger.debug() in loop. For example:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    ...
    log.debug("aaaaa");
    ...
    for(int j = 0; i < 100; j++) {
        ...
        log.debug("bbbb");
    }
}
```

If i add it directly, as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    ...
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("aaaaa");
    }
    ...
    for(int j = 0; i < 100; j++) {
        ...
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("bbbb");
         }
    }
}
```

So, in the loop, it will if() many times. How could i use less if(logger.isDebugEnabled())?

Does anyone have some idea ?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What i care is that so may if() in loop whether will affect performance ?

Consider this code:

```
    boolean logging = log.isDebugEnabled();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        // stuff
        if (logging) { 
            log.debug("Hi Mum!");
        }
        // more stuff
    }
```

The cost of the `if` test could be as small as 2 instructions, depending how the JIT compiler's register allocation pans out.  This is most likely insignificant, unless you are doing *ridiculous* amounts of logging.

However, if the performance hit of those 2 to 4 instructions really matters, then you could consider:

- removing the call to `log` entirely,
- making it conditional on a compile time constant (so that the optimizer can prune the code), or
- hoisting the test out of the loop; e.g. restructuring the code as follows:

  ```
  boolean logging = log.isDebugEnabled();

  if (logging) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          // stuff
          log.debug("Hi Mum!");
          // more stuff
      }
  } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          // stuff
          // more stuff
      }
  }
  ```

However, IMO, the cure is worse than the disease.

---

@Vineet's point is important too.  In practice, the expensive part of something like this:

```
log.debug("Today is " + date);
```

is that the String concatenation expression is evaluated irrespective of the actual logging level.  There are other ways to avoid this overhead apart from an `if` test ... though they *will be more expensive* than an `if` test on a cached flag.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously, there are some String concatenation.

Comment: +1 the reminder about the evaluation portion irregardless of the log level.

Answer (score 2):

Use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Comment: if i use slf4j, there don't need logger.isDebugEnable(), then the effect is the same as logger.debug()? or the same as if(logger.isDebugEnable()) {logger.debug()} ?

Comment: Neither (but close to the latter), have a look at http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance

Answer (score 2):

Store the value of `log.isDebugEnabled()` in a local variable, like this:

```
// Calculate once and cache the answer
boolean areLogging = log.isDebugEnabled();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    ...
    if (areLogging) { 
        log.debug("aaaaa");
    }
    ...
    for (int j = 0; i < 100; j++) {
        ...
        if (areLogging) {
            log.debug("bbbb");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's OK. However, if (areLogging) also will use many times. What i care is that so may if() in loop whether will affect performance ?

Answer (score 2):

Using slf4j has already been pointed out. Specifically, you ought to be using the "parameterized messages" feature of slf4j.

The posted code does not demonstrate the utility in using [parameterized messages](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance). Apparently, "bbbb" will be treated as a String literal (for the compiler can compute it's value at runtime and place it in the constant pool of the class) that will be loaded by the JVM when the class is loaded and pooled in the internal String pool; there is apparently no cost in constructing the log message, and the `log.isDebugEnabled()` invocation is redundant. I'll therefore illustrate the use of parameterized messages with a more descriptive example that demonstrates it's benefits

```
for(int j = 0; i < 100; j++) {
    ...
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) { // this is required by log4j. Without this, on every iteration, a new String object will be created in the following statement.
        log.debug("Loop counter is" + j); // This constructs a new String object only if DEBUG is enabled.
    }
}
```

can be reduced to:

```
for(int j = 0; i < 100; j++) {
    ...
    log.debug("Loop counter is {}", j); //There is no explicit call to log.isDebugEnabled() in this case. The log message will be created only if DEBUG is enabled.
}
```

The String literal `Loop counter is {}` is again pooled in the String intern pool, but at runtime the String object with values `Loop counter is 0`, `Loop counter is 1` etc. will be created by slf4j, only if the DEBUG level is enabled.

Comment: Thanks. But in the large project, there are thousands of files all use log4j, and what i will modify is just severl files under one module. So, i think i will not use slf4j right now.

Comment: Well, that is a different problem. You can cache the `log.isDebugEnabled` return value, for that would be more intuitive. And if your `Logger` object is a per-class static variable, you can have this flag initialized in a similar manner. However, if you cache the value too aggressively, you might also lose the ability to perform dynamic configuration of the Logger.